# Registry modifications from script fail, but work if done interactively

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

I've recently been tasked with creating a PowerShell script that applies a bunch of specific settings to a Windows 10 system, many (but not all) of which require registry modifications, and I've run into some rather interesting behavior.

Here's the minimal test-case I've been using:

```
function set-regkey ($key, $name, $type, $value) {
    if (!(test-path $key)) {
        new-item -path $key -force
    }
    new-itemproperty -path $key -name $name -value $value -propertytype $type -force
}

set-regkey "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7" "EnableAutocorrection" DWORD 0
set-regkey "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7" "EnableSpellChecking" DWORD 0
```

This snippet should turn off the Spell Checking and Autocorrect features found in the Typing section of the Windows Settings application.  When executed line-by-line by manually typing it into a Powershell window, it does exactly that.  I can toggle them on manually, run the test-case by hand, and they get toggled off.  However, when run from a script as the same user by right clicking on the script and selecting 'Run with Powershell', it doesn't work.  I still get the exact same visible output from the `New-ItemProperty` calls, but the settings don't change at all, not even after logging out and back in or rebooting the system.

When trying to modify the exact same keys using the `reg add` command instead of `New-ItemProperty`, I get exactly the same results, it works when run line-by-line by hand, but fails when run as part of a script.

So far, all the Microsoft TechNet documentation I've found has been of no help, and I'm starting to suspect that I'm seeing the effects of registry virtualization, but I can't figure out why or how to prevent it.

Comment: What do you mean by "Interactively" vs. "from Powershell" vs. "interactive Powershell session"?

Comment: Why not configure using Group Policy instead of a script?

Comment: @EBGreen I've updated the question to hpefully be more clear.  In short though, if I run each line by hand in a Powershell window, it works, but if I run it as a script by right clicking the file, it fails.

Comment: How are you running it by right clicking the file?  Are your execution policies set properly?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart It needs to be something that an end user can apply directly with minimal effort, so GPO is out as I don't know of any point-and-click method to apply it.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I've got the execution policy globally set to RemoteSigned on my test system right now, but I've also tried with Unrestricted and saw no difference.

Comment: The idea with a GPO is you configure it centrally and it applies automatically. Users don't need to do _anything_.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart This isn't a case where we could have a central system though.  The setup is for a special account on customer systems that our software needs configured correctly to run (and is a pain in the arse to do by hand).  The general idea is to be able to tell a customer 'Run this script from the install CD and call us back if it still doesn't work.".

Comment: Is your application 32-bit or 64-bit?